# Submit a variable as value of hidden field in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hidden-field

I am trying to pass on a few parameters for a GET request using hidden fields, but I can't seem to set the value to a parameter I am using in my code. I am using the following code in my route:

```
app.post('/upload',function(req, res){
    var fileName = "filename.extension";
    res.write('<br> <form id = "download" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "/download" method = "get" > ' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="fileName" value=""+fileName /> ' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Download file" name="submit"> ' +
        '</form>');
    //document.getElementById('fileName').value = filePath;
}
```

I wanted to try to alter the value of the hidden fields fileName and saveAs via getElementById, but this resulted in an error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: i don't know excatly about what's your expected , you want to get the value "fileName" from the form ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: Yes, I need to put the value of the variable in the form, so I can use it in the /upload route. The answer given by A.B. solved the problem, it was indeed an error in the quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotation pattern in concatenation is not correct

```
   app.post('/upload',function(req, res){
    var fileName = "filename.extension";
    res.write('<br> <form id = "download" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "/download" method = "get" > ' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="'+fileName+'" /> ' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Download file" name="submit"> ' +
        '</form>');
    //document.getElementById('fileName').value = filePath;
}
```

you can also use javascript `concat()` method if you have difficulty matching quotes